# Update object on masterpage through ajax webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

How can i update a repeater on my masterpage, through an ajax webmethod?
I'm having trouble finding the masterpage in my webmethod.

Edit: Is there a better way to do this? Basicly i want to update the repeater after running my ajax webmethod login script.

MasterPage Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_logout').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Webmethods.aspx/logIn",
            data: '{username: "' + username + '", password: "' + password + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // UPDATE REPEATER DATA
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

MasterPage Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Menu" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
</itemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Edit: Not a single answer to this relatively simple question?

Comment: Done. Sorry i thought it was pretty obvious :-)

Comment: Do you really have nothing in the `ItemTemplate` of your Repeater?

Answer (score 1):

Unless things have changed significantly, WebMethods are static methods.  So they will not have access to any properties or fields of the page they are part of - and that includes the objects on the master page.

Another obstacle to this is that things done with AJAX *on the server* do not affect the HTML that has already been rendered to the client.  To change the appearance on the client, you will need to use javascript (presumably jQuery).

What you might be able to do is this:

1. Create a `Repeater` control in code
2. Create a template programmatically (quite do-able, but possibly complex)
3. Bind it to your data source
4. Render it to a string
5. Send the rendered HTML back down to the client
6. Replace the previous rendering of the `Repeater` with the new HTML.
7. Re-create any client-side event handling you might be doing.

Comment: Seems very doable :-) It will be a challenge in my sitaution as my repeater isn't outputting a simple table. I will give it a try though :-)!